# windows service is stopped via SCM, how to find the culprit?

Tags: windows, service, version-control

One of my windows services(3rd party, not windows service) is stopped time to time these days, from the log of it, we can see that it is stopped because it received a SCM shutdown event.

Is there any way to find out what is the culprit? This seems not an easy task to me.

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows Event Logs, in the System log, SCM logs who starts or stops services.  That should tell you what account is doing it, if it's truly a SCM shutdown and not a crash/bug in the service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am asking how to find out what process/script stops the service, any way to track this?

Comment: Can you backtrack it from the event log seeing what user it is, then going through the processes that actually use that service account that might be killing it?